# Android app - can't login: "This site already exists in the app, you can't add it"

Tags: login, android

For some reason I have been logged out of my android app for Wordpress.

I host my own site, so I use "Add self-hosted site" when I try to log in. I enter my user name, password and the address of my site and click "Log in". After a couple of seconds of loading I get the error "This site already exists in the app, you can't add it".

I understand that it already exists in the app, I have been using this app for editing my blog posts before. I wonder why was I logged out in the first place and why can't I log back in (because I was logged in before).
I don't want to delete the app data from the Android settings->apps menu, because I wrote some posts on the app, but haven't uploaded them to my page yet and I don't want to lose this work.

I'm using Wordpress 4.7.4, Android app 7.2

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to hack the lost data by SSH-ing into my android and coping the wordpress app database to my pc and then opening it there wit a sqLite browser

this shouldn't be so hard

Answer (score -1):

Had same problem too. Fixed it by clearing its data and cache in the app manager. This probably deletes local drafts and other local data.